# salt-stack: Trigger, called on state change

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, salt-stack, password-less

I have a state which creates a user on a minion.

This works fine.

The user gets created on the first run, the next N days (or years) it won't be created again.

I want to do some action on a different host after the user was created. For performance reasons I only want to execute this action once, on the first run when the user gets created.

Up to now I search some sort of trigger which gets fired if a state changes. Other solutions are welcome.

**Use case**

After creating the user on the minion I need to insert the minions ssh host-key to a .ssh/known_hosts file to make password less logins work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tackle the use case and not the question I suggest the following:

- use Salt Mine to collect the public keys of your minions
- put the ssh host-keys of the minions into `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`

You can use the [openssh formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/openssh-formula) as a starting point. It contains the scripts for Salt Mine and also how to create a ssh_known_hosts file. It adds a lot of magic with `dig` to discover host names and IP adresses that might be oversized for your environment.

Once it is all set up it should work as follows:

- add a user: host's `ssh_known_hosts` file will used, nothing else needs to be done
- add a minion: update the mine, run the provisioning to on all minions to update the host's `ssh_known_hosts` file.